# Installing Canon D2400U Scanner on XP x64

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, 64-bit, scanner

I'm trying to install an old scanner D2400U from Canon on a Windows XP 64bit SP2.

I have found an official driver at [canon](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0000445.asp), *ScanGear CS-U 6.1.1d*, but when trying to install the scanner (found new USB device, specify driver location, *etc.*), it cannot find the right software, make sure its x64 compatible (which I don't know if the driver I have found is).

I haven't worked with XP x64 before, so my question is:

**Are there any tricks I can use to successfully install this scanner on XP x64 SP2?**

Answer (score 1):

Drivers have to be built for 32 or 64 bit so most likly an old scanner won't have a 64bit driver.  However you should be able to use the scanner with WIA.

Comment: But this still requires a WIA driver - right?

Comment: windows has driver for most scanners for WIA and almost all of them will support twain drivers.  See if there is a cannon twain driver x64